# How do I run different Java processes simultaneously without requesting one Java per process

Tags: java

I was running a Java process with CMD Windows. This code is run by requesting per Java per process. How do I run all processes at once without requesting per request per java?
(bat file)

```
:loop
rem Add port mapping

java -jar portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -routerIndex 0 -add -externalPort 30005 -internalPort 30005 -protocol tcp
java -jar portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -routerIndex 0 -add -externalPort 40000 -internalPort 40000 -protocol tcp 
java -jar portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -routerIndex 0 -add -externalPort 25580 -internalPort 25580 -protocol tcp
java -jar portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -routerIndex 0 -add -externalPort 25570 -internalPort 25570 -protocol tcp
java -jar portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -routerIndex 0 -add -externalPort 25581 -internalPort 25581 -protocol tcp 
java -jar portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -routerIndex 0 -add -externalPort 30009 -internalPort 30009 -protocol tcp

rem Wait for 0 minutes (0.10*1*1 seconds)
timeout 1

goto loop
```

Comment: Portmapper.jar was a Java software i downloaded from others source(github).

Comment: cmd.exe /c ... stuff ...

Comment: Hi,i already read throught the sorce code guide but it only show per Java per Process guide. Is there any way to let cmd run these command simultaneously?

Comment: No? But thanks for your help.